# Batch script that opens a folder based on substring

Tags: batch-file, directory

Objective: Open a specific job folder by only typing in the job number.

Problem: The job folder is located in a few subfolders and I am not sure how to open a folder based on the entered job number.

Example: I type `125`

I can get the directory of the first sub folder which is: `I:\Projects\100 - 150`
The next subfolder is the problem, in the directory `I:\Projects\100 - 150` there are the job folders of `100` to `150` and each of the folders have the customer and type of job it is attached to the name.

Examples:

```
125 - Balloon Services - 100 Red Balloons
126 - Clown Town - Red Noses
```

I've researched quite a bit but all that returns is opening a file with a substring in it based on the extensions. I'm sure there's a way to do this but I just started batch and I'm not very proficient at it yet.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I used, I hope it helps people who come looking, sorry if my question is unclear. This actually fixed the problem, I didn't know the extension for a folder is `*.` and that you want to be in that directory for this code to work.

```
set /p code="Job: "
set b=49
set /a e=%code%+%b%
set dir="I:\Projects\%code:~0,3% - %e%\"
echo "%dir%"
echo "%code:~0,3%"
CD /D %dir%
echo "%CD%"
for /d %%G in ("%code:~0,3%*.") do set name=%%G
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%name%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script code for opening any folder with Windows Explorer which starts with a number and a space as passed with first parameter to the batch file or entered by the batch file user.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if not "%~1" == "" (
    set "JobNumber=%~1"
    goto CheckNumber
)

:UserPrompt
cls
echo.
set "JobNumber="
set /P "JobNumber=Please enter job number: "
if "!JobNumber!" == "" goto UserPrompt

rem The job number specified as parameter or entered by the user
rem should consist of only digits. This is checked for safety reasons.

:CheckNumber
set "InvalidNumber="
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("!JobNumber!") do set "InvalidNumber=%%I"
if not "!InvalidNumber!" == "" goto UserPrompt

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "I:\Projects\%JobNumber% *" /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    if not "%%~dpI" == "I:\Projects\" (
        %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,"%%~I"
        goto EndBatch
    )
)

echo.
echo Could not find a folder with job number %JobNumber%.
echo.

set "Retry=N"
set /P "Retry=Do you want to try another job number (Y/N): "
if /I "!Retry!" == "Y" goto UserPrompt

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` (first argument without surrounding double quotes)
- `cls /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [Windows Explorer Command-Line Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314853) and [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` with redirection operator `>` escaped with `^` to be applied on execution of command **DIR** to suppress the confusing error  message `File not found` output to **STDERR** by redirecting it to device **NUL** if no folder starting with specified job number and a space could be found by command **DIR**.